# Load the Latest Posts by Category in a div via WordPress Menu using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I want my index.php with a horizontal list of category names on the top and when i click on any category name, it would display latest 10 posts in index page on specific div container without refreshing. Is this possible in Wordpress?

Thank you.

### UPDATING With My Code:

### For category menu :

```
<?php $categories = get_categories(); ?>

<ul id="category-menu">
<?php foreach ( $categories as $cat ) { ?>
<li id="cat-<?php echo $cat->term_id; ?>"><a class="<?php echo $cat->slug; ?> ajax" onclick="cat_ajax_get('<?php echo $cat->term_id; ?>');" href="#"><?php echo $cat->name; ?></a></li>
<?php } ?>
```

### html div place holder where posts will load via ajax :

```
<div id="main-container">
<div id="loading-animation" style="display: none;"><img src="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/images/loading.gif"></div>
<div id="category-listing"></div>
```

### jQuery function:

```
<script>
function cat_ajax_get(catID) {
 jQuery("a.ajax").removeClass("current");
 jQuery("a.ajax").addClass("current"); //adds class current to the category menu item being displayed so you can style it with css
 jQuery("#loading-animation").show();
var ajaxurl = '<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>';
 jQuery.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: ajaxurl,
     data: {"action": "load-filter", cat: catID },
     success: function(response) {
         jQuery("#category-listing").html(response);
         jQuery("#loading-animation").hide();
         return false;
  }
  });
  }
  </script>
```

### PHP function :

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_load-filter', 'prefix_load_cat_posts' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_load-filter', 'prefix_load_cat_posts' );
function prefix_load_cat_posts () {
$cat_id = $_POST[ 'cat' ];
     $args = array (
    'cat' => $cat_id,
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'order' => 'DESC'

    );

$posts = get_posts( $args );

ob_start ();

foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
setup_postdata( $post ); ?>

<div>
    <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>/h1>
</div>

<?php } wp_reset_postdata();

$response = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

echo $response;
die(1);
}
```

but when i click on category its not displaying but when i select all and view source code, result

loading without data..

any help ?

Comment: yes it is possible , show your effort / code written by you where you stuck at. SO isn't for you ask and we write on.

Comment: insert my code into my question. now anyone cane help? 
thanks...

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to mess around with the object buffer or the post_attributes() functions in this case:

```
function prefix_load_cat_posts () {
    $cat_id = $_POST[ 'cat' ];
    $args = array (
        'cat' => $cat_id,
        'posts_per_page' => 10,
        'order' => 'DESC'

    );
    $posts = get_posts( $args );
    if($posts) {
        foreach ($posts as $post) { ?>
            <div>
                <h1><a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink($post->ID); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title($post->ID); ?></a></h1>
            </div>
        <?php }
    }
    die();
}
```